# How to cache images of ICEfaces Tree component?

Tags: java, http, jsf, https, icefaces

We've walked into a problem that the images (folder, cross and so on) of our ICEfaces tree will be loaded on each submit.

How can we disable this behaviour? Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download and look at the ICEfaces Component Suite, they faced this same problem and solved it by pre-loading their images on first page request.

Preloading is a standard way of preventing this problem in any similar situation and is not limited to ICEfaces.